# Create a function to match two datasets based on multiple possible combinations

Tags: python, r, loops, stata

I have two datasets with grades and incomplete information in both. I want to match them through a slightly boring system.

One of the datasets looks like this:

| id1 | AverageExam | AverageInternal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 198.7 | 180 |
| 2 | 154.7. | 170 |

The other looks like this:

| schoolid | ExamType | ExamGrade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths | 200 |
| 1 | Maths | 180 |
| 1 | Physics | 200 |
| 1 | Physics | 180 |
| 1 | Biology | 196 |
| 1 | Biology | 180 |

Where in Dataset 1, Average Exam = (MathsGrade + PhysicsGrade + BiologyGrade)/3 of a certain person, and these data is Dataset2.

I don't have the id of students in Dataset 2 so I am not sure which grades belong to which student. My idea is run code and within each school compute all the possible averages of these 3 exams. After that I want to match each line in Dataset 1 to the schoolid from Dataset 2.

I am mostly comfortable with Stata: is there any way to do it? Otherwise, I can try a different package like Python or R (are these more suitable for the effect?).

I have tried to use loop functions in Stata but without success.

Comment: will get problems where multiple students have the same averages?  average marks is not unique enough to perform a join on

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow doesn't work well as a code-writing or counselling service for people who are unsure at your level even about what software is best for them. It's primarily for programmers who have a specific problem and some code and have a specific question about it.  I would seek advice at your institution or work place.

Comment: @murariprasad it might happen but I don't think it will be a very frequent problem